# Get records from this week

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm a bit puzzled on how to get all records from my table where CheckInDate (datetime) occurred THIS WEEK. As in, since Sunday morning at midnight.

To get THIS MONTH was easy:

```
and year(eci.CheckInDate) = year(getdate())
and month(eci.CheckInDate) = month(getdate())
```

...but there is no "week" function similar to MONTH() and YEAR(). Can someone give me a code example on how to do this?

Comment: [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
AND eci.CheckInDate > cast(dateadd(day,1-datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate()) as date)
```

Comment: Be careful because this solution is language dependent.  Specifically as it relates to the first day of the week.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that GetDate() returns a datetime, not date. If you subtract a day from 7/1/2014 18:23, you'll get 6/30/2014 18:23. Your solution will get you Sunday at whatever time you're running it today instead of midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that can be used to do what you want:

```
declare @WeekStart datetime = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, GetDate()), 0)
select @WeekStart
```

It's simpler than it looks. Here's what it is doing:

```
Add to week 0 the number of weeks from 0 to now.
```

Simple yet effective.

By the way, you can use the same method for truncating to second, minute, hour, day, week, month, quarter, etc.